# I am trying to interactive git rebase but it shows me mv: '<path>/git-rebase-todo.new' and '<path>/git-rebase-todo' are the same file

Tags: git, rebase

while rebasing after the resolve the conflict i had use `git rebase --continue` and after that below message printed lots of time on my terminal and still rebasing not get completed.

```
mv: <path>/.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo.new 
and 
    <path>/wa-git/.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo' 
are the same file
```

have anyone idea to solve this problem. it would be very helpful to me.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using `MinGW Shell`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when you have swp files in your directory.

Follow these steps,

1. Use rather `git rebase --continue` for the time being use `git rebase --abort`. This will abort your current rebase and lead you to your previous state.
2. Now you have a local commit which should be synced with remote
3. Before `git pull --rebase` use `git clean -f` to clean all unneccessary files.
4. To ignore other staged files use `git stash`
5. Now use `git pull --rebase` and proceed as you were.

Hope this will solve your problem. It its still not resolved. Try to remove all .swp/ .new files from directory manually and proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. What fixed it for me was setting my editor in my `.gitconfig` file.

```
git config --global core.editor "vim"
```